# What is the best way to learn a new library written in C# using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I recently found the need to learn a new library that didn't come with extensive documentation for a change. The code is written in C# and I am using Visual Studio 2010 as my editor. The library that I am trying to learn did come with a sample driver, but it is fairly large and complex as well. I was wondering if there are any facilities in VS that would allow me to watch the code as it is executing so that I learn as it runs.

Is anyone aware of any tools that I should be looking at in VS and additionally, in general can you specify any other methods that I might use to quickly learn how to use new libraries.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the release build / debug build dlls for this library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write [learning tests](http://mleder.blogspot.com/2010/04/learning-tests.html).

Comment: great idea, I often use TDD and it didn't occur to me that it might be a good way to go about learning as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Red Gate's Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) is a must have for looking into 3rd party library's and there are a couple plugins for it ([FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) is one) that allow you to save your dissasembled files so that you can step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a BreakPoint at any line you you want the program to stop at, and when you run it in debug mode, you will then be able to execute a single line of code at a time, by pressing F11 or F10 (F10 does not go deeper into inner function calls).

Comment: how can you set a breakpoint at every line?

Comment: you don't have to set a breakpoint at EVERY line, just where you want to.